# Adding in a single 2D / Matrix with a string

Tags: python-3.x

How do I add element 1 in all the lists? After that, add element 2? I need to find the percentage of them.

```
rows = [["SOBs", 60, 80, 70, 75], ["Test1", 60, 50, 60, 65], ["Test2", 40, 30, 40, 45], ["Test3", 45, 90, 80, 85], ["CW", 40, 80, 70, 75]]
```

I have tried in this manner:

`sum(sum(rows, [2]))` - this doesn't work

`print(sum(rows[0][1] + [1][1]))` - also doesn't work

So the for element 1 in it would be `60+60+40+45+40 = 245`

Then I take the `245/500*100 = 49%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension?tab=Newest) easily.

```
element = 1
rows = [["SOBs", 60, 80, 70, 75], ["Test1", 60, 50, 60, 65], ["Test2", 40, 30, 40, 45], ["Test3", 45, 90, 80, 85], ["CW", 40, 80, 70, 75]]
sum_1= sum([rows[i][element] for i in range(len(rows))])
element = 2
sum_2= sum([rows[i][element] for i in range(len(rows))])
print((sum_1*100)/(sum_1+sum_2))
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please breakdown the answer?

Comment: you can check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

Comment: Thank you!  I was at this for hours, trying numpy and overload, and other things

Answer (score -1):

Consider it like a table, and use comprehensions, to summarize columns.
Try this

```
rows = [["SOBs", 60, 80, 70, 75], ["Test1", 60, 50, 60, 65], ["Test2", 40, 30, 40, 45], ["Test3", 45, 90, 80, 85],
        ["CW", 40, 80, 70, 75]]
COL_LENGTH = 4  # set as 4, as you have only 4 colums to evaluate

# Create a list of column values for each column index
selected_cols = [[row[i] for row in rows] for i in range(1, COL_LENGTH)]

# Get sum of every column
sums = [sum(col) for col in selected_cols]

# get avg of every column
avgs = [_sum / 5 for _sum in sums]
```